How to make the bones of the two arms have the same direction?
I want the X and Z axis directions of the left and right arms to be the same.I used shift+N but it failed. Is there any other way?


In Edit mode you can roll the bones with Ctrl R but you can't make both the Z and the X of the bones points towards the same global direction

i think this isn't possible because the bones are pointing in opposite directions. you can just align one axis - so either x or z.

oh,you are right, I need to try another way.
